# Rails 4: Turn complicated filter into a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, many-to-many, has-many-through

I have a many-to-many / has-many-through relationship in my connecting my recipe model to my tag model such that:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :recipes, through: :taggings
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :recipe
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end
```

...is there any way to filter for recipes with the same tag through a scope?  I'm new to scopes, but I find them much more useful than methods, and I can only achieve searching and filtering by tag name through a method.

For example this will get me all recipes tagged with a given name:

```
def self.tagged_with(name)
    Tag.find_by_name!(name).recipes
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can basically convert most association-method-chains (though not all*) into a scope

eg I'd try this (note: not tested for bugs) and see how it turned out

```
scope :tagged_with, ->(name) { find_by_name!(name).recipes }
```

If that doesn't work, I'd try something like:

```
scope :tagged_with, ->(name) { where(:name => name).first.recipes }
```

[*] The big issue with using scopes over method-chaining is that `find`/`first` can sometimes do weird things if it doesn't find one... the code in Rails literally defaults to the `all` scope in some cases (this is really weird behaviour that I think shouldn't happen) so for scopes that find just a single item, I will often not bother with a scope and use a class-method as you have originally.

Comment: It doesnt allow for chaining as I expected

Comment: Yes, it won't allow for chaining, because you're picking just one. Can you please update your question with an example of how you'd like to use it (if it were to exist) giving a concrete example other chained methods? It could be that: a) what you want to do can't actually be done b) what you want to do can be better done some other way